# How to Solve sql grammar exception and Unknown column 'id' in springBoot

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, java-ee-7

```
**** customer Class Model*********   
        @Entity
        @Table(name="customer")
        @NamedQuery(name="Customer.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Customer c")
        public class Customer implements Serializable {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
            @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
            private int idCustomer;

            @Column(nullable=false, length=45)
            private String name;


            //bi-directional many-to-one association to Login
            @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
            private Set<Login> logins;

            //bi-directional many-to-one association to Transaction
            @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
            private Set<Transaction> transactions;

            public Customer() {
            }

            public int getIdCustomer() {
                return this.idCustomer;
            }

            public void setIdCustomer(int idCustomer) {
                this.idCustomer = idCustomer;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return this.name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public Set<Login> getLogins() {
                return this.logins;
            }

            public void setLogins(Set<Login> logins) {
                this.logins = logins;
            }

            public Login addLogin(Login login) {
                getLogins().add(login);
                login.setCustomer(this);

                return login;
            }

            public Login removeLogin(Login login) {
                getLogins().remove(login);
                login.setCustomer(null);

                return login;
            }
        }
```

****** Login Class Model*********

```
@Entity
@Table(name="login")
@NamedQuery(name="Login.findAll", query="SELECT l FROM Login l")
public class Login implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int idLogin;

    @Column(length=45)
    private String password;

    @Column(length=45)
    private String uName;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Customer
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idCustomer", nullable=false)
    private Customer customer;

    public Login() {
    }

    public int getIdLogin() {
        return this.idLogin;
    }

    public void setIdLogin(int idLogin) {
        this.idLogin = idLogin;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUName() {
        return this.uName;
    }

    public void setUName(String uName) {
        this.uName = uName;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return this.customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

}
```

MY Controller Method saving login and customer object in the database

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save",method=RequestMethod.POST)public StringsaveCust(
    @ModelAttribute("cust") 
    @Valid Customer cust,
    BindingResult result,
    @RequestParam("pass") String pass , 
    @RequestParam("user") String user){


                if (result.hasErrors()) {
                    return "redirect:/customer";
                } 

                cust = custRepo.save(cust);//using spring DAO to save the object
                Login log = new Login(); //creaing a new login
                log.setUName(user); //setting the user
                log.setPassword(pass); //setting the pass
                log.setCustomer(cust); //setting the customer
                logRepository.save(log); //doesnt save the login . bt customer is saved 
                return "success";

            }
```

I have submitted the two model classes which im using in my springBoot application . In my database there are 2 tables customer and login where in login customerID is a foreign key.
When i try to save my 2 classes in the database customer is saved 
and my login is not saved . i get an error saying

> Unknown column 'id_customer' in 'field list'

i am using thymeleaf in my prohect and error i am seeing in the brower is

> SQLGrammarException:

I think i am doing something wrong in the controller method. Can some one explain me how to solve this.

Comment: In your database, what's the name of the column that references `idCustomer` on the `Customer` database?

Comment: That's the issue. You need to add your column name:  `@Column(unique=true, nullable=false, name="idCustomer")`.

Comment: Does your login table have an id_customer column? Because it should have. By the way, your DB was generated by JPA ou you create it by your self?

Comment: thanks @aribeiro yes that was the issue,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the column name for idCustomer? You didn't put `name="COLUMN_NAME"` in the `@Column` annotation so Hibernate is defaulting your `camelCaseParameter` to columns named `camel_case_parameter`. Here specifically, it's assuming that `idCustomer` maps to a column named `id_customer`.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false) // missing name="COLUMN_NAME"
private int idCustomer;
```

Comment: `@Column(unique=true, nullable=false name="idCustomer")` you mean like this

Comment: It depends what the actual column name is in your database table. If it is "idCustomer", then yes (except add a comma after `nullable = false`). If it is "CUSTOMER_ID", then use `@Column(unique=true, nullable=false, name="CUSTOMER_ID")`.

Comment: bt im not allowed to write name inside the `@Column( name ="idCustomer")` . why is that

Comment: Missing comma. Should be: `@Column(unique=true, nullable=false, name="idCustomer")`

Comment: wow thanks , for one moment i thought  i wont be able to solve this.